ScrollableTabRow maxValue incorrect cannot scroll to the tab I need
I don't think this problem has a solution but if anyone else is experiencing this please let me know what I can do!
Here is the relevant code.  The maxValue of the scrollState is 1125; which I assume is in pixels.  I am using code that dynamically calculates the length of the ScrollableTabRow by multipyling the number of tabs by the width of the tab.  In this case it is 89.dp * 14, with a pixel density of 2.625, which makes a tab width of 233.625 pixels, and with 14 tabs the total is 3270.75.
I'm not sure what to do here; I think I may need to create a custom Composable with a scroller, and possible convert the parent into a Canvas and scroll it.
Does anyone know what I"m doing wrong?
